# PHP: RegEx to parse particular function from the JAVA class

Tags: php, regex

I have to parse JAVA classes with PHP. All java classes implement my interface, so there is always corresponding function required by me in the class. It looks like:

```
public void init(Something driver, Parameters params) { ... }
```

I came up with the following regular expression:

```
/public\s+void\s+init\s*\(\s*Something\s+(\w+)\s*,\s*Parameters\s+(\w+)\s*\)\s*\{([^\}]+)\}\s*/
```

It works fine except the situations when there is "}" symbol somewhere inside the body of my function. Is there any way to handle these situations?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the below regex,

```
public\s+void\s+init\s*\(\s*Something\s+(\w+)\s*,\s*Parameters\s+(\w+)\s*\)\s*\{((?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})?)+[^{}]*)\}\s*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hC4iP0/7)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works but only if there is no unpaired figure brackets in the body of the function. For example, there is comment: `\\} Hello there!`

Comment: is that the final `}` would be at the last of input?

Comment: Unfortunately not, its possible that there are other functions in the class after init function.